# full text search to provide efficient search using java

Tags: java

i have a table where it has 80+ millions of records. i need to provide full text search capability. i know that we can use hibernate search (Lucene). i request you to give any other option other than lucene indexing.

Thanks,
Reddy

Comment: I request you start googling instead of asking everyone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

What data base system are you using? MySQL has FULLTEXT indexing. SQLite has FTS (fast text search) tables. Microsoft SQL Server has full-text indexes. And on and on...

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries for this.

Using plain Java you can create a `NavigableMap<String, Set<Record>>` where the key is all the search-able strings from start at the first, second, third etc character.

If you just want word matches, that will be much more efficient, and you can use the same structure.

Note: This is likely to use a lot of memory, but is simple.